# How can I read a dynamically created textbox (gridview OnRowUpdating)

Tags: asp.net, gridview, aspxgridview

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"  >

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Token" SortExpression="Token" HeaderStyle-Width="100px">
                    <ItemTemplate>                       

                    </ItemTemplate> 
                </asp:TemplateField>

</asp:GridView>
```

update:

after i view the source code of the page thsi is what i see the id of a textbox that i have created dynamic.

```
ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_tabControl_tabUsers_MyControl1_gv_ctl02__token0_3
```

OnRowUpdating:

```
 TextBox _token = gvOrg.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[7].FindControl("_token " + e.RowIndex + "_" + rowId) as TextBox;
```

Update end:

i am adding few textbox dynamic in OnRowDataBound and whe i try getting the value then i am getting null

here is my code:

```
 protected void gv_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {    
            for (int rowId = 0; rowId < 5; rowId++)
            {
                TextBox _token = gvOrg.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[7].FindControl("_token" + rowId) as TextBox;
             }      
        }

protected void gv_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((e.Row.RowState == (DataControlRowState.Edit | DataControlRowState.Alternate)) || (e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Edit))
            {

                if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                {                                             
                    for (int rowId = 0; rowId < 5; rowId++)
                    {    
                        TextBox txtBox = new TextBox();
                        txtBox.ID = "_token" + rowId;
                        txtBox.Text = "token" + rowId;
                        e.Row.Cells[7].Controls.Add(txtBox);  
                    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is how i able to fix the problem: instead of creating in rowdatabound i am creating on RowCreated, hope this will help others.

```
 protected void gridviwe1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {

                if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                {
                    for (int rowId = 0; rowId < 5; rowId++)
                    {
                        TextBox txtBox = new TextBox();
                        txtBox.ID = "_registration" + e.Row.RowIndex + "_" + rowId;
                        txtBox.Text = "_registration" + e.Row.RowIndex + "_" + rowId;
                        e.Row.Cells[7].Controls.Add(txtBox);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Why it is not helping me? I create n number of textboxes in a row of gridview, After postback I recreate them because they are disposed after postback. After postback I can see the text, which I written before postback but cant able to store them in variable.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating textbox for each row - 5 of them... and in each row, each of those textboxes has the same id as the other rows.  You need to at the row's index, for example, to the name of the textboxes when you create them.  You can't have a control on the page with the same id, or else it can't be found correctly.

Here is one way to do that.

```
protected void gv_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((e.Row.RowState == (DataControlRowState.Edit | DataControlRowState.Alternate)) || (e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Edit))
            {

                if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                {                                             
                    for (int rowId = 0; rowId < 5; rowId++)
                    {    
                        TextBox txtBox = new TextBox();
                        txtBox.ID = "_token" + e.Row.RowIndex + "_" + rowId;
                        txtBox.Text = "token" + rowId;
                        e.Row.Cells[7].Controls.Add(txtBox);  
                    } 
        }
```

I can't test that this is the complete solution, but it is a place to start.

Comment: good catch, i did update my code and also update my `OnRowUpdating` but still getting null - i updated my question.