# Get the Value of a Programmatically added TextBox using FindControl in a Loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, textbox, findcontrol

I have a GridView that's bound to a DropDownList.  The GridView is updated by a SQL query when the DropDownList's index is changed.  Values in the GridView's Cells are turned into Labels and a TextBox is programmatically added.  OnClick of a button the values of the Labels and TextBoxes are looped through and then submitted to a shopping cart.

I can't get the value of the TextBoxes into my loop.  FindControl can't find the ID of the TextBox?  I think it has to do with adding the TextBox programmatically?

Forgive my ignorance and coding approach... I'm only a year into ASP.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    NPBasePage _bp = (NPBasePage) Page;
    string myUserID = _bp.UserID;
    UserIDLabel.Text = myUserID;
    if (Page.IsPostBack) {} else {}
}

protected void RapidOrderEntry_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) {
        foreach(TableCell c in e.Row.Cells) {
            TextBox l = new TextBox();
            l.ID = "QuantityTextBox";
            l.Text = "0";
            l.CssClass = "QuantityTextBox";
            Label b = new Label();
            b.ID = "PartNumberLabel";
            b.CssClass = "labelNone";
            Label x = new Label();
            x.Text = "&nbsp;";
            x.CssClass = "null";
            b.Text = c.Text;
            if (c.Text == "&nbsp;") {
                c.Controls.Add(x);
            } else {
                c.Controls.Add(l);
                c.Controls.Add(b);
            }
        }
    }
}

protected void AddTheseItemsToMyShoppingBagButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    NPBasePage _bp = (NPBasePage) Page;
    NPOrder order = new NPOrder(_bp.UserID, _bp.SessionID);
    if (!order.Initialized) {
        order.CreateDefaultOrder(_bp.UserID, _bp.AccountID, _bp.SessionID);
    }
    for (int x = 0; x < RapidOrderEntry.Rows.Count; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < RapidOrderEntry.Rows[x].Cells.Count; y++) {
            NPOrderDetail newdet = order.AddPart((RapidOrderEntry.Rows[x].Cells[y].Text), Int32.Parse(((TextBox)RapidOrderEntry.Rows[x].Cells[y].FindControl("QuantityTextBox")).Text), _bp.CatalogCode, "", _bp.PriceList, 0, NPConnection.GetConfigDB("Commerce", "CalculationUoM"));
        }
    }
    Response.Redirect("/commerce/cart.aspx");
}
```

I am sure the problem lies in this and my loop:

```
Int32.Parse(((TextBox)RapidOrderEntry.Rows[x].Cells[y].FindControl("QuantityTextBox")).Text)
```

Error retuned is "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."  If I manually set the integer to 1 like this:

```
NPOrderDetail newdet = order.AddPart((RapidOrderEntry.Rows[x].Cells[y].Text), 1, _bp.CatalogCode, "", _bp.PriceList, 0, NPConnection.GetConfigDB("Commerce", "CalculationUoM"));
```

It works like a charm.  But the customer needs to be able to type in their own quantity.

## EDIT

Here is my full code -- hopefully that will help.

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Collections.Generic" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="netpoint.api" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="netpoint.api.catalog" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="netpoint.api.commerce" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="netpoint.classes" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="netpoint.api.data" %>

<%@ Page language="c#" Inherits="netpoint.classes.NPBasePage" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<link rel="Shortcut Icon" href="/favicon.ico">
<title>Rapid Order Entry</title>
<link href="../../assets/common/themes/2011/css/partner.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../assets/common/themes/2011/js/common.js"></script>

<style>
h2 {
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #2D210B;
    font-weight: bolder;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}
p {
    font-family: Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 14px;
}
.red {
    background-color: #F66;
    color: #333;
}
.yellow {
    background-color: #FFDC78;
    color: #333;
}
.green {
    background-color: #B4DCB4;
    color: #333;
}
.null {
    background-color: #CCC;
}
#RapidOrderEntry th {
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
}
.color {
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 67px;
}
.labelNone {
    display: none;
}
.QuantityTextBox {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
</style>



<script runat="server">
    
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        NPBasePage _bp = (NPBasePage) Page;
        string myUserID = _bp.UserID;
        UserIDLabel.Text = myUserID;
    
        if (Page.IsPostBack) {} 
        else {}
    }
    
    protected void RapidOrderEntry_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) {
          if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            int cellIndex = 0;
            foreach (TableCell c in e.Row.Cells)
            {
                TextBox l = new TextBox();
                l.ID = string.Format("QuantityTextBox_{0}_{1}", e.Row.RowIndex, cellIndex);
                l.Text = "0";
                l.CssClass = "QuantityTextBox";
                Label b = new Label();
                b.ID = string.Format("PartNumberLabel_{0}_{1}", e.Row.RowIndex, cellIndex);
                b.CssClass = "labelNone";
                Label x = new Label();
                x.Text = "&nbsp;";
                x.CssClass = "null";
                b.Text = c.Text;
                if (c.Text == "&nbsp;")
                {
                    c.Controls.Add(x);
                }
                else
                {
                    c.Controls.Add(l);
                    c.Controls.Add(b);
                }

                cellIndex++;
            }
        }
    }
    
    protected void AddTheseItemsToMyShoppingBagButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        
        
        
        NPBasePage _bp = (NPBasePage) Page;
        NPOrder order = new NPOrder(_bp.UserID, _bp.SessionID);
        if (!order.Initialized) {
            order.CreateDefaultOrder(_bp.UserID, _bp.AccountID, _bp.SessionID);
        }
        for (int x = 0; x < RapidOrderEntry.Rows.Count; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < RapidOrderEntry.Rows[x].Cells.Count; y++) {
                
            TextBox tb = (TextBox)RapidOrderEntry.Rows[x].Cells[y].FindControl(string.Format("QuantityTextBox_{0}_{1}", x, y));
            int t = Int32.Parse((tb).Text);
            NPOrderDetail newdet = order.AddPart((RapidOrderEntry.Rows[x].Cells[y].Text), t, _bp.CatalogCode, "", _bp.PriceList, 0, NPConnection.GetConfigDB("Commerce", "CalculationUoM"));    
            }
        }
        Response.Redirect("/commerce/cart.aspx");
    }
    
    

    protected void PLMDropDownAlpha_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        RapidOrderEntryDS.SelectParameters.Clear();
        PLMDropDownNum.SelectedIndex = 0;
        string PartNo = PLMDropDownAlpha.SelectedValue;
        RapidOrderEntryDS.SelectCommand = "SELECT Color, [1] [XS], [2] [S], [3] [M], [4] [L], [5] [XL], [6] [2XL], [7] [3XL], [8] [4XL], [9] [5XL], [10] [6XL], [11] [LT], [12] [XLT], [13] [2XLT], [14] [3XLT], [15] [4XLT], [16] [5XLT], [17] [6XLT], [18] [OSFM], [19] [ADJ] FROM (SELECT CASE SUBSTRING(PartsMaster.PartNo, CHARINDEX('-', PartsMaster.PartNo) + 1, CHARINDEX('-', PartsMaster.PartNo, CHARINDEX('-', PartsMaster.PartNo) + 1) - (CHARINDEX('-', PartsMaster.PartNo) + 1)) WHEN 'SDL' THEN 'Saddle' WHEN 'TBC' THEN 'Tobacco' WHEN 'APN' THEN 'Aspen' WHEN 'ASP' THEN 'Asphalt' WHEN 'BLK' THEN 'Black' WHEN 'FKH' THEN 'FldKhaki' WHEN 'GVL' THEN 'Gravel' WHEN 'GRV' THEN 'Gravel' WHEN 'MOS' THEN 'Moss' WHEN 'NVY' THEN 'Navy' WHEN 'SAW' THEN 'Sawdust' WHEN 'OS' THEN 'OSFM' WHEN 'BAR' THEN 'Barley' WHEN 'SGE' THEN 'Sage' WHEN 'STN' THEN 'Stone' WHEN 'MOC' THEN 'Mocha' WHEN 'DSK' THEN 'Dusk' WHEN 'ROS' THEN 'Rose' WHEN 'APL' THEN 'Apple' WHEN 'PER' THEN 'Persimon' WHEN 'SND' THEN 'Sand' WHEN 'MUS' THEN 'Mustard' WHEN 'GRN' THEN 'Green' WHEN 'BRN' THEN 'Brown' WHEN '0HD' THEN 'CamoHD' WHEN 'WHE' THEN 'Wheat' WHEN '0M4' THEN 'CamoMax4' WHEN 'OLV' THEN 'Olive' WHEN '0HG' THEN 'CamoHDG' WHEN 'CHR' THEN 'Charcoal' WHEN 'CAN' THEN 'Canyon' WHEN 'GRY' THEN 'Gray' WHEN 'RED' THEN 'Red' WHEN 'BLZ' THEN 'Blaze' WHEN 'MAR' THEN 'Maroon' WHEN 'WLD' THEN 'PPK' WHEN 'PPK' THEN 'OSFM' WHEN 'NGT' THEN 'Night' WHEN 'SLR' THEN 'Solar' WHEN 'WDF' THEN 'Wildfire' WHEN '0AP' THEN 'CamoAP' WHEN 'DOX' THEN 'DrkOxford' WHEN 'SUN' THEN 'Sunset' WHEN 'MDN' THEN 'Midnight' WHEN 'SHD' THEN 'Shadow' WHEN 'PTL' THEN 'Petal' WHEN 'LTN' THEN 'LtTan' WHEN 'CHC' THEN 'Chocolate' WHEN 'SMK' THEN 'Smoke' WHEN 'FTG' THEN 'Fatigue' WHEN 'CAC' THEN 'Cactus' WHEN 'ROP' THEN 'Rope' WHEN 'STL' THEN 'Steel' WHEN 'CLY' THEN 'Clay' WHEN 'KHA' THEN 'Khaki' WHEN 'CHA' THEN 'Charcoal' WHEN 'ERH' THEN 'Earth' WHEN 'MAZ' THEN 'Maize' WHEN 'PNK' THEN 'Pink' WHEN 'CSN' THEN 'Chestnut' WHEN 'FTG' THEN 'Fatigue' WHEN 'INK' THEN 'Ink' WHEN 'PTY' THEN 'Putty' WHEN 'BRK' THEN 'Bark' WHEN 'DWD' THEN 'Driftwood' WHEN 'EVG' THEN 'Evergreen' WHEN 'RWD' THEN 'Redwood' WHEN 'TWN' THEN 'Tawny' WHEN 'SLT' THEN 'Slate' WHEN 'TPE' THEN 'Taupe' WHEN 'TAN' THEN 'Tan' WHEN 'CHL' THEN 'Chili' WHEN 'ELM' THEN 'Elm' WHEN 'LAK' THEN 'Lake' WHEN 'DUN' THEN 'Dune' WHEN 'LDN' THEN 'Loden' WHEN 'STR' THEN 'Stream' WHEN 'SNS' THEN 'Sandston' WHEN 'DNM' THEN 'Denim' WHEN 'PEP' THEN 'Pepper' WHEN 'DBR' THEN 'DKBrown' WHEN 'MUD' THEN 'Mud' WHEN 'BRZ' THEN 'Bronze' WHEN 'GPH' THEN 'Graphite' WHEN 'WHT' THEN 'White' WHEN 'SPC' THEN 'Spice' WHEN 'DGR' THEN 'Dark Green' WHEN '0PA' THEN 'Pink Camo AP' WHEN 'PNE' THEN 'Pine' WHEN 'LGN' THEN 'Lagoon' WHEN 'OPA' THEN 'CamoPnkAP' WHEN '0AB' THEN 'CamoAPBlk' WHEN '0AE' THEN 'CamoAPEvg' WHEN 'CBL' THEN 'Colbalt' ELSE substring(PartsMaster.PartNo, 6, 3) END [Color], CASE WHEN PartsAttribute.AttributeCode = 'size' AND PartsAttribute.Dimension1 = 'XS' THEN 1 WHEN PartsAttribute.AttributeCode = 'size' AND PartsAttribute.Dimension1 = 'S' THEN 2 WHEN PartsAttribute.AttributeCode = 'size' AND PartsAttribute.Dimension1 = 'M' THEN 3 WHEN PartsAttribute.AttributeCode = 'size' AND PartsAttribute.Dimension1 = 'L' THEN 4 WHEN PartsAttribute.AttributeCode = 'size' AND PartsAttribute.Dimension1 = 'XL' THEN 5 WHEN PartsAttribute.AttributeCode = 'size' AND PartsAttribute.Dimension1 = '2XL' THEN 6 WHEN PartsAttribute.AttributeCode = 'size' AND PartsAttribute.Dimension1 = '3L' THEN 7 WHEN PartsAttribute.AttributeCode = 'size' AND PartsAttribute.Dimension1 = '4XL' THEN 8 WHEN PartsAttribute.AttributeCode = 'size' AND PartsAttribute.Dimension1 = '5XL' THEN 9 WHEN PartsAttribute.AttributeCode = 'size' AND PartsAttribute.Dimension1 = '6XL' THEN 10 WHEN PartsAttribute.AttributeCode = 'size' AND PartsAttribute.Dimension1 = 'LT' THEN 11 WHEN PartsAttribute.AttributeCode = 'size' AND PartsAttribute.Dimension1 = 'XLT' THEN 12 WHEN PartsAttribute.AttributeCode = 'size' AND PartsAttribute.Dimension1 = '2XLT' THEN 13 WHEN PartsAttribute.AttributeCode = 'size' AND PartsAttribute.Dimension1 = '3XLT' THEN 14 WHEN PartsAttribute.AttributeCode = 'size' AND PartsAttribute.Dimension1 = '4XLT' THEN 15 WHEN PartsAttribute.AttributeCode = 'size' AND PartsAttribute.Dimension1 = '5XLT' THEN 16 WHEN PartsAttribute.AttributeCode = 'size' AND PartsAttribute.Dimension1 = '6XLT' THEN 17 WHEN PartsAttribute.AttributeCode = 'size' AND PartsAttribute.Dimension1 = 'OSFM' THEN 18 WHEN PartsAttribute.AttributeCode = 'size' AND PartsAttribute.Dimension1 = 'ADJ' THEN 19 ELSE '20' END [size], CASE WHEN PartsInventory.OnHand > 0 THEN PartsMaster.PartNo ELSE NULL END [stock_value] FROM PartsAttribute INNER JOIN PartsMaster ON PartsAttribute.PartNo = PartsMaster.PartNo LEFT OUTER JOIN PartsInventory ON PartsMaster.PartNo = PartsInventory.PartNo WHERE (LEN(PartsMaster.PartNo) > 9) AND (PartsMaster.ProductLinePartNo LIKE '" + PartNo + "') AND ((PartsAttribute.AttributeCode = N'size' OR PartsAttribute.AttributeCode = N'color')) AND PartsInventory.WarehouseCode IN ('01') AND (PartsAttribute.PartNo = PartsMaster.PartNo) AND (PartsMaster.PartNo = PartsInventory.PartNo) AND (PartsAttribute.PartNo = PartsInventory.PartNo) AND (PartsInventory.OnHand IS NOT NULL OR PartsAttribute.AttributeCode IS NOT NULL OR PartsMaster.PartNo IS NOT NULL OR PartsAttribute.Dimension1 IS NOT NULL)) AS source PIVOT (min(stock_value) FOR [Size] IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19])) AS pivoted";
        RapidOrderEntry.DataBind();
    }
    protected void PLMDropDownNum_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        RapidOrderEntryDS.SelectParameters.Clear();
        PLMDropDownAlpha.SelectedIndex = 0;
        string PartNo = PLMDropDownNum.SelectedValue;
        RapidOrderEntryDS.SelectCommand = "SELECT Color, [1] [XS], [2] [S], [3] [M], [4] [L], [5] [XL], [6] [2XL], [7] [3XL], [8] [4XL], [9] [5XL], [10] [6XL], [11] [LT], [12] [XLT], [13] [2XLT], [14] [3XLT], [15] [4XLT], [16] [5XLT], [17] [6XLT], [18] [OSFM], [19] [ADJ] FROM (SELECT CASE SUBSTRING(PartsMaster.PartNo, CHARINDEX('-', PartsMaster.PartNo) + 1, CHARINDEX('-', PartsMaster.PartNo, CHARINDEX('-', PartsMaster.PartNo) + 1) - (CHARINDEX('-', PartsMaster.PartNo) + 1)) WHEN 'SDL' THEN 'Saddle' WHEN 'TBC' THEN 'Tobacco' WHEN 'APN' THEN 'Aspen' WHEN 'ASP' THEN 'Asphalt' WHEN 'BLK' THEN 'Black' WHEN 'FKH' THEN 'FldKhaki' WHEN 'GVL' THEN 'Gravel' WHEN 'GRV' THEN 'Gravel' WHEN 'MOS' THEN 'Moss' WHEN 'NVY' THEN 'Navy' WHEN 'SAW' THEN 'Sawdust' WHEN 'OS' THEN 'OSFM' WHEN 'BAR' THEN 'Barley' WHEN 'SGE' THEN 'Sage' WHEN 'STN' THEN 'Stone' WHEN 'MOC' THEN 'Mocha' WHEN 'DSK' THEN 'Dusk' WHEN 'ROS' THEN 'Rose' WHEN 'APL' THEN 'Apple' WHEN 'PER' THEN 'Persimon' WHEN 'SND' THEN 'Sand' WHEN 'MUS' THEN 'Mustard' WHEN 'GRN' THEN 'Green' WHEN 'BRN' THEN 'Brown' WHEN '0HD' THEN 'CamoHD' WHEN 'WHE' THEN 'Wheat' WHEN '0M4' THEN 'CamoMax4' WHEN 'OLV' THEN 'Olive' WHEN '0HG' THEN 'CamoHDG' WHEN 'CHR' THEN 'Charcoal' WHEN 'CAN' THEN 'Canyon' WHEN 'GRY' THEN 'Gray' WHEN 'RED' THEN 'Red' WHEN 'BLZ' THEN 'Blaze' WHEN 'MAR' THEN 'Maroon' WHEN 'WLD' THEN 'PPK' WHEN 'PPK' THEN 'OSFM' WHEN 'NGT' THEN 'Night' WHEN 'SLR' THEN 'Solar' WHEN 'WDF' THEN 'Wildfire' WHEN '0AP' THEN 'CamoAP' WHEN 'DOX' THEN 'DrkOxford' WHEN 'SUN' THEN 'Sunset' WHEN 'MDN' THEN 'Midnight' WHEN 'SHD' THEN 'Shadow' WHEN 'PTL' THEN 'Petal' WHEN 'LTN' THEN 'LtTan' WHEN 'CHC' THEN 'Chocolate' WHEN 'SMK' THEN 'Smoke' WHEN 'FTG' THEN 'Fatigue' WHEN 'CAC' THEN 'Cactus' WHEN 'ROP' THEN 'Rope' WHEN 'STL' THEN 'Steel' WHEN 'CLY' THEN 'Clay' WHEN 'KHA' THEN 'Khaki' WHEN 'CHA' THEN 'Charcoal' WHEN 'ERH' THEN 'Earth' WHEN 'MAZ' THEN 'Maize' WHEN 'PNK' THEN 'Pink' WHEN 'CSN' THEN 'Chestnut' WHEN 'FTG' THEN 'Fatigue' WHEN 'INK' THEN 'Ink' WHEN 'PTY' THEN 'Putty' WHEN 'BRK' THEN 'Bark' WHEN 'DWD' THEN 'Driftwood' WHEN 'EVG' THEN 'Evergreen' WHEN 'RWD' THEN 'Redwood' WHEN 'TWN' THEN 'Tawny' WHEN 'SLT' THEN 'Slate' WHEN 'TPE' THEN 'Taupe' WHEN 'TAN' THEN 'Tan' WHEN 'CHL' THEN 'Chili' WHEN 'ELM' THEN 'Elm' WHEN 'LAK' THEN 'Lake' WHEN 'DUN' THEN 'Dune' WHEN 'LDN' THEN 'Loden' WHEN 'STR' THEN 'Stream' WHEN 'SNS' THEN 'Sandston' WHEN 'DNM' THEN 'Denim' WHEN 'PEP' THEN 'Pepper' WHEN 'DBR' THEN 'DKBrown' WHEN 'MUD' THEN 'Mud' WHEN 'BRZ' THEN 'Bronze' WHEN 'GPH' THEN 'Graphite' WHEN 'WHT' THEN 'White' WHEN 'SPC' THEN 'Spice' WHEN 'DGR' THEN 'Dark Green' WHEN '0PA' THEN 'Pink Camo AP' WHEN 'PNE' THEN 'Pine' WHEN 'LGN' THEN 'Lagoon' WHEN 'OPA' THEN 'CamoPnkAP' WHEN '0AB' THEN 'CamoAPBlk' WHEN '0AE' THEN 'CamoAPEvg' WHEN 'CBL' THEN 'Colbalt' ELSE substring(PartsMaster.PartNo, 6, 3) END [Color], CASE WHEN PartsAttribute.AttributeCode = 'size' AND PartsAttribute.Dimension1 = 'XS' THEN 1 WHEN PartsAttribute.AttributeCode = 'size' AND PartsAttribute.Dimension1 = 'S' THEN 2 WHEN PartsAttribute.AttributeCode = 'size' AND PartsAttribute.Dimension1 = 'M' THEN 3 WHEN PartsAttribute.AttributeCode = 'size' AND PartsAttribute.Dimension1 = 'L' THEN 4 WHEN PartsAttribute.AttributeCode = 'size' AND PartsAttribute.Dimension1 = 'XL' THEN 5 WHEN PartsAttribute.AttributeCode = 'size' AND PartsAttribute.Dimension1 = '2XL' THEN 6 WHEN PartsAttribute.AttributeCode = 'size' AND PartsAttribute.Dimension1 = '3L' THEN 7 WHEN PartsAttribute.AttributeCode = 'size' AND PartsAttribute.Dimension1 = '4XL' THEN 8 WHEN PartsAttribute.AttributeCode = 'size' AND PartsAttribute.Dimension1 = '5XL' THEN 9 WHEN PartsAttribute.AttributeCode = 'size' AND PartsAttribute.Dimension1 = '6XL' THEN 10 WHEN PartsAttribute.AttributeCode = 'size' AND PartsAttribute.Dimension1 = 'LT' THEN 11 WHEN PartsAttribute.AttributeCode = 'size' AND PartsAttribute.Dimension1 = 'XLT' THEN 12 WHEN PartsAttribute.AttributeCode = 'size' AND PartsAttribute.Dimension1 = '2XLT' THEN 13 WHEN PartsAttribute.AttributeCode = 'size' AND PartsAttribute.Dimension1 = '3XLT' THEN 14 WHEN PartsAttribute.AttributeCode = 'size' AND PartsAttribute.Dimension1 = '4XLT' THEN 15 WHEN PartsAttribute.AttributeCode = 'size' AND PartsAttribute.Dimension1 = '5XLT' THEN 16 WHEN PartsAttribute.AttributeCode = 'size' AND PartsAttribute.Dimension1 = '6XLT' THEN 17 WHEN PartsAttribute.AttributeCode = 'size' AND PartsAttribute.Dimension1 = 'OSFM' THEN 18 WHEN PartsAttribute.AttributeCode = 'size' AND PartsAttribute.Dimension1 = 'ADJ' THEN 19 ELSE '20' END [size], CASE WHEN PartsInventory.OnHand > 0 THEN PartsMaster.PartNo ELSE NULL END [stock_value] FROM PartsAttribute INNER JOIN PartsMaster ON PartsAttribute.PartNo = PartsMaster.PartNo LEFT OUTER JOIN PartsInventory ON PartsMaster.PartNo = PartsInventory.PartNo WHERE (LEN(PartsMaster.PartNo) > 9) AND (PartsMaster.ProductLinePartNo LIKE '" + PartNo + "') AND ((PartsAttribute.AttributeCode = N'size' OR PartsAttribute.AttributeCode = N'color')) AND PartsInventory.WarehouseCode IN ('01') AND (PartsAttribute.PartNo = PartsMaster.PartNo) AND (PartsMaster.PartNo = PartsInventory.PartNo) AND (PartsAttribute.PartNo = PartsInventory.PartNo) AND (PartsInventory.OnHand IS NOT NULL OR PartsAttribute.AttributeCode IS NOT NULL OR PartsMaster.PartNo IS NOT NULL OR PartsAttribute.Dimension1 IS NOT NULL)) AS source PIVOT (min(stock_value) FOR [Size] IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19])) AS pivoted";
        RapidOrderEntry.DataBind();
    }
    protected void ViewShoppingBag_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        Response.Redirect("/commerce/cart.aspx/");
    }
</script>



</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">

<div align="center" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;"> 

<p>You can use these dropdown lists to quickly jump to all of one product's sizes and colors.</p>

      
        <asp:DropDownList ID="PLMDropDownAlpha" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
            DataSourceID="ListByPLMDSAlpha" DataTextField="PartName" 
        DataValueField="PartNo" 
        onselectedindexchanged="PLMDropDownAlpha_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="225px" >
        </asp:DropDownList>
 
&nbsp;&nbsp;
       
        <asp:DropDownList ID="PLMDropDownNum" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
            DataSourceID="ListByPLMDSNum" DataTextField="PartName" 
        DataValueField="PartNo" 
        onselectedindexchanged="PLMDropDownNum_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="225px" >
        </asp:DropDownList>
        
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="ListByPLMDSNum" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:connString %>" 
    SelectCommand="
        SELECT 'disabled' AS PartNo, ' Products by Part Number ' AS PartName, NULL AS PartCode
        UNION ALL
        SELECT PartNo, CASE
            WHEN PartNo LIKE '%-OD-%' THEN left(PartCode,4) + ' - '  + PartName + ' ' + 'Camo'
            WHEN PartNo LIKE '%-AP-%' THEN left(PartCode,4) + ' - ' + PartName + ' ' + 'Camo'
            WHEN PartNo LIKE '%-0HD-%' THEN left(PartCode,4) + ' - ' + PartName + ' ' + 'Camo'
            WHEN PartNo LIKE '%-0M4-%' THEN left(PartCode,4) + ' - ' + PartName + ' ' + 'Camo'
            ELSE left(PartCode,4) + ' - ' + PartName END PartName, PartCode
        FROM PartsMaster
        WHERE (ProductLineFlag = 'Y') AND (StaticThumbnail <> '')
        ORDER BY PartCode
    ">
</asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="ListByPLMDSAlpha" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:connString %>" 
    SelectCommand="
        SELECT 'disabled' AS PartNo, ' Products by Part Name ' AS PartName
        UNION ALL
        SELECT PartNo, CASE 
            WHEN PartNO LIKE '%-OD-%' THEN PartName + ' ' + 'Camo'
            WHEN PartNO LIKE '%-AP-%' THEN PartName + ' ' + 'Camo'
            WHEN PartNO LIKE '%-0HD-%' THEN PartName + ' ' + 'Camo'
            WHEN PartNO LIKE '%-0M4-%' THEN PartName + ' ' + 'Camo'
            ELSE PartName END
        FROM PartsMaster
        WHERE (ProductLineFlag = 'Y') AND (StaticThumbnail <> '')
        ORDER BY PartName
    ">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
 
 
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />

  
  </asp:SqlDataSource>
  <asp:GridView ID="RapidOrderEntry" runat="server" datasourceid="RapidOrderEntryDS" OnRowCreated="RapidOrderEntry_RowCreated" autogeneratecolumns="False" style="width:790px;margin:0 auto;text-align:center;">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Color" HeaderText="" itemstyle-cssclass="color" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="XS" HeaderText="XS" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="S" HeaderText="S" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="M" HeaderText="M" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="L" HeaderText="L" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="XL" HeaderText="XL" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="2XL" HeaderText="2XL" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="3XL" HeaderText="3XL" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="4XL" HeaderText="4XL" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="5XL" HeaderText="5XL" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="6XL" HeaderText="6XL" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LT" HeaderText="LT" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="XLT" HeaderText="XLT" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="2XLT" HeaderText="2XLT" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="3XLT" HeaderText="3XLT" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="4XLT" HeaderText="4XLT" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="5XLT" HeaderText="5XLT" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="6XLT" HeaderText="6XLT" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="OSFM" HeaderText="OSFM" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ADJ" HeaderText="ADJ" />
    </Columns>
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
      <div style="height:200px;" align="center"> 
            <h2 ID="EmptyDataTemplateOn" style="font-weight:normal;position:relative;top:80px;color:#999;display:none;">The Inventory Matrix for this item is currently unavailable due to insufficient stock information.<br />Item inventories are updated frequently.  Please try again later.</h2>
            <h2 ID="EmptyDataTemplateOff" style="font-weight:normal;position:relative;top:85px;color:#999;">Please choose an item.</h2>
      </div>
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
  </asp:GridView>
  <asp:SqlDataSource ID="RapidOrderEntryDS" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:connString %>" />
        <SelectParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="PartNo" Type="String" />
            </SelectParameters>
  </asp:SqlDataSource>


    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="AddTheseItemsToMyShoppingBagButton" runat="server" Text="Add These Items to My Order" onclick="AddTheseItemsToMyShoppingBagButton_Click" />

<asp:Label ID="UserIDLabel" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:Label>

</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's a better idea to generate the TextBox fields or Labels 
[using TemplateFields.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10527859/how-to-add-dynamic-texbox-in-gridview-at-runtime)

## EDIT

You can create the controls in the RowCreated Event Handler, naming the controls with a unique name:

```
protected void RapidOrderEntry_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            int cellIndex = 0;
            foreach (TableCell c in e.Row.Cells)
            {
                TextBox l = new TextBox();
                l.ID = string.Format("QuantityTextBox_{0}_{1}", e.Row.RowIndex, cellIndex);
                l.Text = "0";
                l.CssClass = "QuantityTextBox";
                Label b = new Label();
                b.ID = string.Format("PartNumberLabel_{0}_{1}", e.Row.RowIndex, cellIndex);
                b.CssClass = "labelNone";
                Label x = new Label();
                x.Text = "&nbsp;";
                x.CssClass = "null";
                b.Text = c.Text;
                if (c.Text == "&nbsp;")
                {
                    c.Controls.Add(x);
                }
                else
                {
                    c.Controls.Add(l);
                    c.Controls.Add(b);
                }

                cellIndex++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Then You can retrieve the control like this:

```
 protected void AddTheseItemsToMyShoppingBagButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        for (int x = 0; x < RapidOrderEntry.Rows.Count; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < RapidOrderEntry.Rows[x].Cells.Count; y++)
            {
                TextBox tb = (TextBox)RapidOrderEntry.Rows[x].Cells[y].FindControl(string.Format("QuantityTextBox_{0}_{1}", x, y));
                int t = Int32.Parse((tb).Text);
            }
        }
 }
```

Comment: I agree.  But the SQL query is a convoluted pivot table.  We need the rows to be columns so I ended up formatting most of the GridView in the SQL query itself.

Comment: See this question, may be your code is in the wrong event: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4751565/how-can-i-read-a-dynamically-created-textbox-gridview-onrowupdating

Comment: I can't use var because our server is ASP 2.0.  I tried subbing in `string tb` and `int t` but it didn't work.  I haven't used a var before, forgive me.

I used your RowCreated handler but the controls don't get added.  They only get added when I use a RowDataBound.

Comment: You should replace "var tb" for "TextBox tb". Anyway I've tried in RowCreated and worked fine. I'm using .net 3.5. Then I've changed to 2.0 and worked fine too. Visual Studio 2008

Comment: For some reason the controls are only added when I use the RowDataBound but then the `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` error happens when the button is clicked.  

If I use your code, and click, then it works! With quantities of all 0's -- which is to be expected.  So how can I make the RowCreated work to input the correct quantities?

I put my full code in the orignal post.  Hope that helps.  I am new to the RowCreated Event.

Comment: You need the cell data values that are provided in the RowDataBoundEvent, but in that event, to add controls has no effect. I think you need to use a different approach, TemplateField instead of DataField, brings you the posibility to add controls with the values you want